# python Cachetools can items have different ttl?

Tags: python, pandas, caching

Im using `@cachetools.func.ttl_cache(maxsize=3, ttl=3600, timer=time.time, typed=False)` to cache different data frames. The function being wrapped doesn't build the DF itself, but given an argument calls the right function.

Depending on the argument the DF may be time consuming or fast to build, given that I want to modify the item ttl (time-to-live). So that item 1 may have ttl=3600 while item 2 ttl=10800.

Is that functionality supported? using a global variable or any other way? [docs](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cachetools.TTLCache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can, however, create your own custom caches for use with cachetools.  You can check out the implementation of the ttlcache in ttl.py for an example.  It's pretty straightforward.

Unfortunately, the ttlcache itself isn't really designed in such a way that you could conveniently subclass it and override the logic that determines when items in the cache expire.  It would be easy enough to just go in and tamper with the expiration dates for the links, but the fact that they used double underscores to prefix all the link-related logic is kind of a clue that the author really didn't want you to do that.

I'd recommend just implementing your own cache.

Answer (score 5):

Will is most likely correct, but just in case you want to try, I think subclass TTLCache and overwrite one function should work:

```
from cachetools import Cache, TTLCache

cache = TTLItemCache(maxsize=2, ttl=100)
# ttl=100
cache.__setitem__('key1', 'val1')
# ttl=200
cache.__setitem__('key2', 'val2', ttl=200)

class TTLItemCache(TTLCache):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value, cache_setitem=Cache.__setitem__, ttl=None):
        super(TTLItemCache, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        if ttl:
            link = self._TTLCache__links.get(key, None)
            if link:
                link.expire += ttl - self.ttl
```

Comment: This solution will make [cache expiry](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools/blob/f8a166b63a3f3adef1cb8d2d81417812bddc0240/src/cachetools/__init__.py#L471) less effective, since the expiry relies on a linked list where items appear in order of expiry. i.e. items may fill the cache (and count against `maxsize`) even though they are long past expiry.